# Java - Set Integer Values to Max Image Size

Tags: java, image-processing, random

I have read an image in and I want to randomly set values for `int x` and `int y` but only up to the width and height of the image respectively and not below `0,0` so that they do not exceed the boundaries of the image.

Something like this:

```
read image //I have this already
assign random value to int x up to maxWidth of image but >= 0
assign random value to int y up to maxHeight of image but >= 0
end
```

Typically, almost all of the images that I am working with are approximately 424 x 424.

I am ultimately looking to end up with values such as:

```
int x = 325;
int y = 10;
```

or

```
int x = 424
int y = 351
```

or

```
int x = 109
int y = 230
```

Each time I run the code, the values for `x` and `y` will be reassigned randomly as before.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried using e.g. [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)?

Comment: @Mick: What do you mean by *"Each time I run the code, the values for x and y will be reassigned randomly as before."*?  It's the **"as before"** part that is weird.  Do you want it to be random, but reproducible?  If that's the case, you want to use a fixed seed for your PRNG.  For example instead of *new Random(System.currentTimeMillis())* you'd instead do *new Random(42)*.

Comment: Yes, I would like new values assigned to `x` and `y` each time the program is run, which are >=0,0 and <= maxHeight & maxWidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like:

```
import java.util.Random;

..stuff..

// create a random instance - you only need one of these
Random r=new Random();

..stuff..

// create a random co-ordinate within the image rectangle
int x=r.nextInt(image.getWidth());
int y=r.nextInt(image.getHeight());
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are asking how to obtain the width and height of an image, but if not then simply get a random int between 0 and each image dimension.

```
final int width, height;
Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
final int x = rand.nextInt(width);
final int y = rand.nextInt(height);
```

Comment: I am able to obtain the image width and height; I just need to generate values up to the max value for both with and height, but not less than 0.